# How can I get "education" to feature above "work" on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

If somebody searches my name my work details appear under my name. Is there a way to get my education details to appear instead without having to remove my employment information?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict your employment information only to certain audiences (e.g. fellow employees) and so most of the world will only see your education details without you having to remove anything.